# TcpClient and UdpClient throwing errors

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, udp, windows-7-x64

On two systems running Windows 7 x64 and VS2012 U1 and using .Net 4 I get the error "An invalid argument was supplied" if I call UdpClient or TcpClient.

I've tried a number of ports and I've verified that the ports are not already bound but I get the same error every time.

I've also tried running the code with elevated privileges to no avail.

Test code:

```
try
        {
            using (UdpClient client = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 123)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Port is open");
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:\n{0}", error.Message);
        }
```

Error Output:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=An invalid argument was supplied
  Source=System
  ErrorCode=10022
  NativeErrorCode=10022
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
       at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient..ctor(IPEndPoint localEP)
       at GetNTPTime.Program.Main(String[] args) in z:\My Documents\Dropbox\Dev\C#\_Example\GetNTPTime\GetNTPTime\Program.cs:line 15
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

As a note I get the same error if I simply call **UdpClient client = new UdpClient();**

Comment: Q: Have you tried with a specific port# (instead of InAddrAny)?  EXAMPLE: `UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(11000);  udpClient.Connect("www.myurl.com", 11000);`

Comment: A: Yes, same result on both systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that my code was being executed from a Dropbox folder and for some reason that was causing the issues even if Dropbox wasn't running on the system at the time. If I moved the code base to the desktop and run it everything works.

## Update

I did some more research and I've found that it is not Dropbox causing the issue but Cloudfogger, if I close Cloudfogger everything works.

Comment: And of course Cloudfogger is encrypting the files you have in your Dropbox folder.  Q: Either moving your files *out* of Dropbox, or turning Cloudfogger *off* resolves the problem, correct?  Be sure to "accept" your answer when you get a chance.

Comment: Yes, moving the files out or shutting down Cloudfogger fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I see your using port 123 in your example, that may be a bad choice as it falls within the reserved range, in particular 123 is used by the [Network Time Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). Try to use unreserved ports above 1024.

If you still get an error with

```
UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
```

my guess is there is a problem with your system. Try running the same executable on a different machine if you can.

Comment: Port 123 is the port that I would like to use because I'm writing a NTP client/server but I've tried using ports in the unreserved range with no luck. I have tried running the same code on two systems with the same result on both.

Comment: @Sane - Could you step through your code and tell me exactly which lines throws the exception (its not clear from your post)?

Comment: UdpClient throws the exception or if I change it to TcpClient I get the same exception. For example, if I use your above code I get the exception.

Comment: Ok, can you do this try { UdpClient client = new UdpClient(); } catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); } and paste the error string into the comments.

Comment: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An invalid argument was supplied
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
   at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient.createClientSocket()
   at GetNTPTime.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 15

Comment: No firewalls enabled on ether system.

Comment: Thanks for the help found my issue.