# C# Winform to Connect to Device Using IP

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets

I need to create an application that allows the user to connect to a device (a piece of hardware that will be sent arguments/commands) via wifi (wifi is end goal but I am settling at the moment for any connection) and then send commands to said device.  I know some C# and some sockets/IP stuff, but not sockets/IP using C#.  The visual, GUI side of the program is not what I am struggling with.  I cannot seem to get the socket up and running and make any real connection.  I keep getting the "An Invalid Argument was Supplied" exception.

Any tips on this particular issue or help with C# networking/sockets/etc. are welcome.

I declare a new socket by:

```
Socket sck;
sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
```

The exception is thrown when it tries to process the "sck = new Socket(...);"

Code in Question:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace InternetConnect
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Global Variables
        int portNumber = 0;
        string ipAddress = "";
        TcpClient client;

        Socket sck;
        EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;

        // Needs to be defined at some point
        // These are just holding a place for now
        string extraIP = "127.0.0.1";
        string extraPort = "135";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            try
            {
                sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void connectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddressTextBox.Text), Convert.ToInt32(portNumberTextBox.Text));
                MessageBox.Show("Before Bind");
                sck.Bind(epLocal);

                MessageBox.Show("After Bind");

                epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(extraIP), Convert.ToInt32(extraPort));
                sck.Connect(epRemote);

                MessageBox.Show("After Connect");

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
                sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);

                connectButton.Text = "Connected";
                connectButton.Enabled = false;
                sendButton.Enabled = true;
                outgoingTextBox.Focus();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            ipAddress = ipAddressTextBox.Text;
            // To make sure there are no letters in the IP Address
            int errorCounter = Regex.Matches(ipAddress, @"[a-zA-Z]").Count;
            if (errorCounter == 0)
            {
                if (ipAddress != "")
                {
                    // To make sure the port number is entered without letters
                    if (int.TryParse(portNumberTextBox.Text, out portNumber))
                    {
                        WriteToStatusBar("IP Address and Port Number Valid");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid Port Number.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid IP Address.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid IP Address.");
            }
            #endregion

            try
            {
                client = new TcpClient();
                WriteToStatusBar("Connecting...");
                client.Connect(ipAddress, portNumber);
                WriteToStatusBar("Connected");
                outgoingTextBox.Text = "Enter message to be sent to the device...";

                client.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You've shown us where the exception is thrown, but not what exception gets thrown.  Are you able to provide the exception details?

Comment: Upon clicking "View Detail" when the exception occurs, it tells me: "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException {"An invalid argument was supplied"}   I appreciate all help!

Comment: What other details would you like me to provide?

Comment: Why are you using udp and connect ? Udp is not connection oriented at all. And why is there the tcpclient at the bottom of the code. Which is it, udp or tcp ? And why do you need to connect twice. Looks to me like you only need tcpclient.

Comment: I have updated the code excerpt.  Which parts seem to deem unnecessary?

Comment: I am getting two exceptions currently.  One on the: "'sck1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);'" and one on the "'sck1.Bind(ep);'".

Comment: From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b86d684%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page: "`If this constructor throws a SocketException, use the SocketException.ErrorCode property to obtain the specific error code. After you have obtained this code, refer to the Windows Sockets version 2 API error code documentation in the MSDN library for a detailed description of the error.`"

Comment: You don't need the socket code at all, only the tcpclient code.

Comment: @Octopoid, how do I gain the SocketException.ErrorCode

Comment: @PhilipStuyck I can do what I need to do without sockets?  Won't I need the use of sockets to connect to a device through wifi/IP?

Comment: If you want to know what error code the Socket ctor is returning, you need to use `catch (SocketException ex) { Debug.WriteLine(ex.ErrorCode.ToString()); }` - i.e. `ErrorCode` is a property of the `SocketException` instance.

Comment: A tcpclient is a wrapper on top of a socket. Ie a tcpclient uses a socket so that you don't have to.

Comment: @Octopoid thank you! I searched for that for a long time and never came across that.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Gotcha.  Makes more sense now, thank you sir!

Comment: @PhilipStuyck How do I use tcpclient without using sockets?  I keep searching for helpful code examples but the ones I have progressed through seem to all use sockets.  Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: See my answer below, it is a bit more elaborate and did not fit a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per request of the OP some information about using TcpClient and even TcpListener in case you need to create a server as well. Following link will help you get started with using TcpClient :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

or this one in code project covers both client and server: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1415/Introduction-to-TCP-client-server-in-C

in that code (the first link) you'll find following statement : stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
You want to write multiple times to the socket then suppose you write the same data twice you can do simply :

```
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

At the receiver, you have to realise that because TCP is streaming, you might receive to 2 send 'messages' in one receive or scattered over multiple receives.

Further in the code you will find :

```
stream.Close();         
client.Close();
```

Which ends the communication and closes the socket, sending after doing the close is not possible anymore.

Using sockets, but also tcpclient and tcplistener (because they are based on sockets), is something that I consider a bit advanced material. Without really understanding what streaming is, what IP addressing is, what TCP, UDP is, how to use sockets , some basic understanding of threads. It is easy to get lost. I am a professional programmer, and I did not touch this material after I read quite a lot of information about it.

The best thing to do is to do more investigation, based on examples on the internet & books. And ask very specific dedicated questions using this medium. Elaborate questions have a tendency to get closed without proper answer which will lead to frustration of course.

Comment: Man, I really appreciate all of your help.  You have been super helpful.  Another note, will it matter in regards to your answer that I am trying to do all of this while also using winforms?

Comment: No that does not matter. Please upvote this answer or mark as solution if this was helpful to you.

Comment: Will do man, currently working through your information.  Also, I will not need to do the server side of the code since my device will be acting as a server and have its own IP address etc., correct?

Comment: correct, but start simple using localhost , ie 127.0.0.1. Run both client and server on the same machine first.

Comment: So, implemented the client side before doing the server side.  I know, I probably should do the server side as well.  But, my program does not get very far into the code before I get the same exception "An invalid argument was supplied".  This exception is thrown when it processes the line of code: `TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();` No sockets even used.  Any thoughts?  (Ps, I really appreciate your input.  I know you could be doing so many other things than helping me haha)

Comment: On what kind of machine are you running this, what is already installed, try a different machine.  Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819089/tcpclient-and-udpclient-throwing-errors. You normally don't get this kind of exception just for creating a tcpclient.

Comment: Dell machine, Windows 7.  Yes, it is kind of strange.  If I take the project to another computer that also has Visual Studio and run it there, I do not get the "Invalid Argument" exception and it goes further into the code.

Comment: then you have to check what is installed on that machine where it does not work, like in the link I provided. Please upvote this answer or mark as solution if this was helpful to you.